Find the distance from the apex of a trapezium to the midpoint of the opposite side
If you have a trapezium $ABCD$ ($BC\parallel AD$) whose average base measures $2$m.
Calculate $DM$ with $"M"$ being the midpoint of $AB$, in addition $CD^2-2.MC^2 = 2m^2$.
(Answer:$3$)

I made a drawing and tried
$\triangle DMH: DM^2=MH^2+DH^2$
$\frac{BC+AD}{2} = 2m \implies BC+AD = 4m$
$MC^2 = CP^2+PM^2 = MH^2+PM^2$
$\therefore DM^2-DH^2 = MC^2-PM^2$
but I can't find the way

Let $M$ and $N$ be the mid-points of $AB$ and $DC$ respectively.
Denote $\theta=\angle MCD$, $x=CN$, $y=CM$.
By mid-point theorem, $MN=\frac{1}{2}(BC+AD)=2m$ (given). By considering
$\Delta MCN$, we obtain $(2m)^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}-2xy\cos\theta$. That
is, $4m^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}-2xy\cos\theta$. It is given that $CD^{2}-2MC^{2}=2m^{2}$,
so $(2x)^{2}-2y^{2}=2m^{2}$, i.e., $2x^{2}-y^{2}=m^{2}$. By considering
$\Delta CMD$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
DM^{2} & = & CM^{2}+CD^{2}-2.CM.CD.\cos\theta\\
 & = & y^{2}+4x^{2}-4xy\cos\theta\\
 & = & \left[2x^{2}+2y^{2}-4xy\cos\theta\right]+\left[2x^{2}-y^{2}\right]\\
 & = & 8m^{2}+m^{2}\\
 & = & 9m^{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $DM=3m$
